# VIsual Studio Community 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio

Всем привет. Хочу себе поставить лицензионную (dreamspark) VIsual Studio Community 2015, но при установке выдаёт ошибку

[image: vs_community.exe]

Они и вправду давно были на моём пк, но я их удалил. Поиски через кмд 
`dir /s vs_ultimate.exe` и `dir /s vs_proffesional.exe` так же не дали результатов, искал на всех дисках. Windows 10 обновлённая с Windows 8.1 (там тоже такая же ошибка была). Заранее спасибо.

[Лог журнала](https://vk.com/doc277790772_411162937)

Comment: На ссылке "файл журнала" нажмите - внутри будет четко описанно, где он искал и что нашел конфликтующего.

Comment: Добавил журнал.

Comment: выдает "Ошибка: Этот документ был удалён из общего доступа."

Answer (score 1):

У вас остались записи в базе Windows Installer (WI). Первое что вам нужно это выяснить код продукта, это GUID. Можете изучить логи, можете погуглить. После этого качаете [Install Uninstall Fixit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall). Запускаете, выбираете проблемы с удалением, он там что-то ищет, может найдёт ваши студии в списке, но скорее всего нет, так что выбираете, как там и написано опцию "Not Listed". Он вас спросит GUID продукта (вот для этого они нам и были нужны). После этого он должен вычистить остатки из базы WI. Если это не поможет, то можете рискнуть что-то поправить руками через Orca, но это совсем уж экстрим, на таком этапе проще уже винду переставить на мой взгляд (или просто продолжить пользоваться Pro/Enterprise).

Comment: fixit не поддерживает 10 винду =( А переустанавливать не хочется, у меня 2 оси

Comment: Могу вам посочувствовать.

Answer (score 1):

Решается всё очень просто, но нудно. В реестре вбиваешь в поиск 14.0 (точное соответствие, только разделы) и удаляешь всё, кроме офиса. Если не помогло, то можно поискать все папки 12.0 и тоже их удалить. В итоге всё у меня встало нормально, только риск этого способа уж очень велик.